# How to scrape from a website which shows no tags in its source code?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am parsing a website using lxml and python.
The problem is that I am able to see that element when I am inspecting it through Firebug extension in Mozilla FireFox. But it shows no presence in page source which I am reading
The code is

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree
page=urllib.urlopen(url)
response=page.read()
x=etree.HTML(response)
company=x.xpath('//div[@class="name"]')
```

All the div tags with class="name" are clearly seen in Inspecting through Mozilla Firebug extension. But there is no presence on HTML page source code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` elements with `class="name"` are loaded via a set of XHR calls. Instead of manually figuring out what requests you need to make to get the data, use the [`AngelList API`](https://angel.co/api).

Moreover, according to the [`Terms of Use`](https://angel.co/terms), web-crawling is illegal:

> Crawling the Service is permissible in accordance with this agreement,
>   but scraping the Service without the prior consent of AngelList except
>   as permitted by this agreement is expressly prohibited

Comment: thanks for alerting me of legal terms. I will use AngelList api

Answer (score 0):

The page source specifies the initial structure of the page, but this [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM) can be changed entirely by JavaScript scripts that are executed on the page. It's very likely that this is what's going on, making the page source code look different from the actual running page.

So you'd need something that lets you execute the needed JavaScript functions, and also lets you inspect the modified DOM. If you're using Python, one option is to use [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/pyside) which provides Python bindings for Qt (perhaps you can also use [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), but I'm not that familiar with it) and Qt itself has support for a WebKit-based browser engine.

The following Python 2 code is loosely inspired by the Qt example [webkit-domtraversal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/webkit-domtraversal.html) and prints the DOM right after a page is loaded. I'm suspecting that this is still not enough for your purpose, so you may need to add a small extra delay to let all the JavaScript in the page do its work. Currently, just the HTML tag names are written to the screen, but using the documentation of [QWebElement](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html) it should be easy to modify this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit
import sys

class MyWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()

        self.page = QtWebKit.QWebPage(self)
        self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)

        self.view.setPage(self.page)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        self.page.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinished)
        self.page.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

    def loadFinished(self, ok):
        print "Load finished", ok

        doc = self.page.mainFrame().documentElement()
        self.examineChildElements(doc)

    def examineChildElements(self, parent, indent = 0):

        self.printElement(parent, indent)

        elem = parent.firstChild()
        while not elem.isNull():
            self.examineChildElements(elem, indent + 2)
            elem = elem.nextSibling()

    def printElement(self, elem, indent):
        print " "*indent + elem.tagName()

def main():
    print "Enter URL:"
    url = raw_input()

    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin(url);
    w.show()
    a.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```